# Duda sobre Array con tope en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en C++. En la última clase vimos algo que el profesor denomino "*Array con tope*". Yo queriendo profundizar este concepto de manera autodidacta lo busqué pero no pude encontrar nada similar.

Un ejemplo del código que manejamos es:

```
#define N 20
#define TAM 100
typedef char palabra[N];
struct fecha { int dd; int mm; int aa; };

struct empleado { palabra nombre; palabra apellido; int cedula; fecha
nacimiento; };

fecha leo_fecha() { fecha f; cin >> f.dd >> f.mm >> f.aa; return f; }



empleado leo_empleado() {
empleado e;
cout << "Ingrese nombre: " << endl;
cin >> e.nombre;
cout << "Apellido: " << endl;
cin >> e.apellido;
cout << "Ingrese cedula: " << endl;
cin >> e.cedula;
cout << "Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento: ";
e.nacimiento=leo_fecha();
return e; }

struct arr_emp { empleado e [N]; int tope; };

arr_emp creo_vacioE() {
arr_emp a;
a.tope=0; }

bool es_vacioE(arr_emp a) {
return (a.tope==0); }

void agrego(arr_emp &a, empleado e) { a.e[a.tope]=e; }

void imprimoE(arr_emp a) {

for (int i=0; i<a.tope; i++)
imprimo_empleado(a.e[i]); }

int este_enE (arr_emp a, int cedula) {
for(int i=0; i<a.tope; i++)
{
    if(a.e[1].cedula==cedula)
    {
    return i;
    }
    else
        {
        return -1;
        }
 } }

main () {
arr_emp a;
empleado e;
a=creo_vacioE();
if (es_vacioE(a)==0)
{
cout << "El arreglo esta vacio" << endl;
}
e=leo_empleado();
agrego(a,e);

}
```

Agradecería que me digieran a que concepto esto refiere. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Federico, recomendación:  si tienes alguna duda sobre algun término lo primero que debes hacer es pedirle la explicacion a tu profesor, o al menos la bibliografía para que asi puedas aprender.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta ¿Puedes reformularla?

Answer (score 1):

A lo que se refiere tu profesor es a 2 conceptos diferentes

Boundaries o Limites en castellano, que representan el tamaño maximo de cualquier objeto pixeles, arrays etc, ¿Cuantas manzanas caben en esta caja? boundary = 20.

Los array de forma primitiva se tratan recorriendo punteros sin limite, por tanto, necesitas un limite para no salirte.

Por lo cual siempre necesitas un array(puntero al inicio) y un limite eg. 20
lo cual significa que tenemos un array que va desde inicio hasta inicio + 20
este seria el "tope" que tu profesor te expresa.

Answer (score 0):

El concepto de *array* primitivo en C no es más que un puntero a una dirección de memoria donde comienza el *array*.

Puedes verlo como una *flecha* que apunta al lugar donde debes empezar a buscar cualquier elemento que este en el *array*. Al escribir una instrucción del estilo:

```
int a = arr[5];
```

lo que se hace realmente es ir a la **posición** donde comienza el *array* y avanzar 5 posiciones más, dado que los elementos de un *array* primitivo están todos seguidos en la memoria.

Esta forma de manejar *arrays* es muy básica, y no contempla cosas como límites, es decir, cual es la **capacidad** del *array* o **cuántos elementos tiene**, que son dos cosas distintas.

En el caso que planteas, tu `tope` representa cuántos elementos hay actualmente en el *array*. Lo puedes deducir de la función:

```
bool es_vacioE(arr_emp a) {
    return (a.tope==0); 
}
```

Para determinar si un *array* está vacío, se mira si `tope` es igual a 0.

---

Más allá de esto, creo que la función

```
void agrego(arr_emp &a, empleado e) { 
    a.e[a.tope]=e; 
}
```

está incompleta. Primero, faltaría comprobar que el *array* no este ya lleno, y segundo, es necesario actualizar el `tope`, porque el *array* tiene un elemento más

```
void agrego(arr_emp &a, empleado e) {
    if(a.tope < N){
        a.e[a.tope]=e; 
        a.tope++;
    }
}
```